# Empty GROUP BY in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I have a table of association rules (say antecedent, succedent, and support). I would like to draw them in GraphViz. I have became so lazy that I don't want to code any imperative script for that, I would just like to select the DOT source directly in SQL.

My idea was as simple as

```
SELECT string_agg('"' || x || '" -> "' || y || '" [weight="' || weight || '"]', E'\n')
FROM rules
GROUP BY ...;
```

Then I realized I'm having surprising difficulties with the `GROUP BY` clause. Because I need to group all the rows, the clause should be left empty.

What is the most elegant way of saying `GROUP BY NOTHING`, i.e. perform the grouping on an empty set of columns?

Comment: just don't use the `GROUP BY`?

Comment: @Lamak Aaah, very easy, thanks, thought I tried it but obviously I didn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To aggregate *all* rows, you don't need to form groups with `GROUP BY` and can can just omit the `GROUP BY` clause. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-GROUPBY)

> If there are aggregate functions but no `GROUP BY` clause, the query is
> treated as having a single group comprising all the selected rows.

Or (if you are building the query string dynamically) you could use any constant expression like:

```
...
GROUP BY true
```

You can't use <strike>`GROUP BY 1`</strike> for this purpose because integer numbers serve as positional references (ordinal numbers) to `SELECT` list items in the `GROUP BY` clause:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

Comment: A missing or constant `GROUP BY` raises an error when used with a `ORDER BY`clause.

Comment: @jnas: An aggregate query without `GROUP BY` returns exactly *one* row. So why `ORDER BY`? Even if that occurs due to inflexible query concatenation: `ORDER BY` doesn't necessarily require and explicit `GROUP BY`. It works with output column names or ordinal positions. Only input column(s) would have to be listed in `GROUP BY`, but that would change the output for multiple distinct values in said input column(s), or else be just noise. And `ORDER BY $constant` never raises an error, it's a no-op.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GROUPING SETS` feature [see documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-GROUPING-SETS)

Like so:

```sql
...
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((<your comma-separated list of columns>))
```

so if your list of columns is empty, this ends up looking like `GROUP BY GROUPING SETS (())` what happens to be a valid syntax, behaving the same as having no `GROUP BY` at all